# Format Pandas DataFrame to Excel - Index Names

Tags: pandas, excel, pandas-styles

How can I specify the format to Index Names using `df.style` method? I was hoping that there was something like `apply_map_index_name` but I don't believe there is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [this may help](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply_index.html)

Comment: It does not unfortunately as it just changes the index labels

Answer (score 0):

That's an open issue (*see [*GH48936*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48936)*, *that is yours*).

As a workaround, you can use CSS selectors with [`set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) ([*which is not Excel-friendly*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Methods-to-Add-Styles)) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5), columns=list("ABCDE"))

d1 = {
    "selector": ".index_name:before",
    "props": """content:'stack'; font-weight:lighter;
                color:white;background-color:#f48024"""    
}

d2 = {
    "selector": ".index_name:after",
    "props": "content:'overflow'; font-weight:bold"
}

df.rename_axis("").style.set_table_styles([d1, d2]).pipe(display)
```

Output :

[image]